# How to Disconnect Stripe Express from Your Twitter Profile?

Tags: twitter, stripe-payments

I recently subscribed to Twitter Blue or X Premium and wanted to enable ad revenue. However, I encountered an issue on the Stripe Connect page. I mistakenly used the same email address & password that I had previously used for a test creation of a Stripe account but with a different country which logged me into that exact account. Now I'm stuck because I can't provide information from different countries, such as SSN and bank details.

I can't go back or use a new email because it's already connected. Even though I didn't complete the required setup, it shows as "you have not completed setting your Stripe account." I've tried reaching out to Stripe, but they informed me that they have no control over third-party integrations. As for Twitter or X, I've received the usual response – no response at all.

I've made numerous attempts to open a support case, but there has been no response. I expected better customer support, especially since I paid for these features. My concern is that my case may become irrelevant after my Twitter Premium subscription expires. If they respond after a month and my subscription has ended, I might have to pay again. This is frustrating because I was planning to rely on ad revenue to continue my subscription, but I couldn't even experience it due to this issue.

Is there anything I can do on my end other than waiting for Twitter to respond, which has already taken days? Closing my Stripe account won't resolve the issue because it won't close the platform account (the Stripe Express account created when I used my test Stripe info on Twitter's connect page). Stripe mentioned that only Twitter can close this account from their end. Also, I can't add another account to replace it, as I'm informed that my account already has a Stripe account linked to a different email. This situation is confusing and extremely frustrating, and the quality of customer support has been beyond trash to put it lightly.

I tried contacting Twitter support a unbelievable amount of times over the span of a couple of days, 0 responses, just bots saying they will review it and nothing happens of course.

I even tried contacting them straight in DMS through the X premium page a bot said to describe the problem in details and the live agent will review it, of course over 24 hours later, nothing.

Stripe informed me that deleting the stripe account with that email won't really delete the one created through twitter's API.